# Batch command returning weird error

Tags: batch

I have been spending hours working on a command to iterate through sub-folders and find what you searched for, but it is returning this:

Searching for: Text Doc.txt

C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\"Text Doc.txt"

Search finished!

The quotes surrounding "Text Doc.txt" were annoying me, so I tried to remove them normally (set path=%path:"=%). Now I am getting a strange error that I can't find a solution for:

\ATI was unexpected at this time.

Here are the contents of the batch file:

```
@echo off

set search=%*

if not [%1] == [] (
    echo(
    echo Searching for: %search%
    echo(
    for /r %cd% %%f in ("%search%") do (
        if exist %%f (
            set path=%%f
            set path=%path:"=%
            echo %path%
            echo(
        )
    )
    echo Search finished!
)
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: I think you might find your solution here:  [Error running command shell scripts that include parentheses](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2524009) and/or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190295/x-was-unexpected-at-this-time-batch-script)

Comment: Thanks, but why was it working before I tried to fix the quotes?

Comment: Sorry, I honestly don't know, I'm not much of a batch user, I just poked around to look for similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do not change the [PATH variable](http://ss64.com/nt/path.html). Moreover, avoid of changing further [Windows Environment Variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html), changing them might cause problems.

> The `%PATH%` environment variable contains a list of folders. When a
>   command is issued at the CMD prompt, the operating system will first
>   look for an executable file in the current folder, if not found it
>   will scan `%PATH%` to find it.

[`FOR /R` Loop through files (Recurse subfolders)](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html): Unlike some other variants of the `FOR` command you must include a wildcard (either `*` or `?`) in the 'set' to get consistent results returned (with `FOR /R [[drive:]path] %%parameter IN (set) DO command` syntax pattern).

Your script could be as follows, if should be launched `895551.bat "Text Doc.txt"` (with filename surrounding quotes):

```
@echo off
set "search=%~1"
set "myPathToFile="
if not "%~1"=="" (
    echo(
    echo Searching for: "%search%"
    echo(
    for /r "%cd%" %%f in ("%search%"*) do (
        if exist %%f (
            set "myPathToFile=%%~f"
            echo "%%~f"
            echo(
        )
    )
    echo Search finished!
) else (
    echo Nothing to search!
)
echo last found myPathToFile "%myPathToFile%"
```

If should be launched without filename surrounding quotes: `895551.bat Text Doc.txt` then your script could start as follows:

```
@echo off
set "search=%*"
set "myPathToFile="
if not "%1"=="" (
```

Required reading:

- [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- [Windows Command-Line Reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx)

Output:

```
==>895551.bat
Nothing to search!
last found myPathToFile ""

==>895551.bat "Text Doc.txt"

Searching for: "Text Doc.txt"

Search finished!
last found myPathToFile ""

==>type nul>files\"Text Doc.txt"

==>895551.bat "Text Doc.txt"

Searching for: "Text Doc.txt"

"d:\bat\files\Text Doc.txt"

Search finished!
last found myPathToFile "d:\bat\files\Text Doc.txt"

==>type nul>"files\folder 1\Text Doc.txt"

==>895551.bat "Text Doc.txt"

Searching for: "Text Doc.txt"

"d:\bat\files\Text Doc.txt"

"d:\bat\files\folder 1\Text Doc.txt"

Search finished!
last found myPathToFile "d:\bat\files\folder 1\Text Doc.txt"

==>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I completely forgot that my path variable will mingle with the real one. Even though I just edited it to include the folder with my commands in it.